# Snowflake history query tag, add current user and other information

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to add current_user() and other hardcoded values by using query tag in snowflake history.

Something like :

ALTER SESSION SET QUERY_TAG = " EXECUTED_BY = current_user(); EXECUTED_THROUGH = DBT MODEL"

Answer (score 0):

No, [QUERY_TAG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#query-tag) only allows a string and doesn't interpret it, so in your case QUERY TAG will actually show the following string:

```
EXECUTED_BY = current_user(); EXECUTED_THROUGH = DBT MODEL
```